# sum of a property in list object join with other three list object

Tags: linq, join, sum, anonymous-types

I have a join composed from three list of objects and I would to get the sum of values of a property that is three level under the one of the object's list root :

```
objectList1.CollateralList[0].COL_MOV[0].collValueField[0].Value
```

where `Value` is a string,instead `CollateralList`, `COL_MOV` and `collValueField` are array of objects.
I'm tryng this solution:

```
var joinList = (from colPos in objectList1
join csa in objectList2 on new { X1 = colPos.Counterparty, X2 = colPos.CSDType, X3 = colPos.Name } equals new { X1 = csa.Customer, X2 = csa.Type, X3 = csa.Cod_CSA }
join anag in objectList3 on new { Y1 = csa.Customer } equals new { Y1 = anag.CustomerID }
select new
{                               colPos.CollateralList.ToList().Sum(c=>c.COL_MOV.ToList().Sum(d=>d.CollValue.ToList().Sum(e=>Convert.ToDoubl(e.Value))))
}).ToList();
```

But I got the error,

> "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

The problem is reported on the sum instruction.
Could somebody help me please?

Comment: The error message is because anonymous object fields are only named implicitly from field or property access expressions - did you Google the error? Put a field name in front of the expression in the anonymous object.

Comment: Ok, I've add Value = colPos.CollateralListToList().Sum(......

Comment: And now is ok but I got a ArgumentNullException because a source collection is empty. I've tryed to use DefaultEmpty but intellisense show my the message "not contain definition for 'DefaultEmpty' and the best extension method overload....". Any suggestion is welcome!!!! Thanks a lot